# Link between Differential Geometry and Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request

I know about Differential Geometry basics; it deals with Manifolds and other topological spaces and studies them deeply. On the other hand Complex Analysis is Calculus on complex numbers; in Complex Analysis, we have Complex Functions, Complex Differentiation and integration. My question is to find a link, i.e. a connection between these two fields, and their application in fields like Physics.

Comment: complex analysis, in general, is a part of differential geometry

Comment: How, It looks really Strange for me??

Comment: This is fun -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere

Comment: @Masacroso Where did you get this idea? There are small areas of overlap, but this is an outrageous statement.

Comment: @TedShifrin I had read some books of complex analysis from a geometric point of view. It exposes complex analysis from a differential geometry point of view. Indeed many essential theorem, as the residue theorem, can be seen as particular cases of homotopy theory, what is an essential part of any advanced book of differential geometry. Also some textbooks (that doesn't necessarily enhance the geometric point of view) start complex analysis after some discussion about differential forms and some preliminary topics on differential geometry, as the Poincaré lemma

Comment: @Masacroso Homotopy is basic algebraic topology. The appearance of hyperbolic geometry via the Ahlfors-Schwarz-Pick lemma is the main elementary connection. The big Picard theorem can be proved using hyperbolic metrics, as well. But I think you should be careful when you make statements like this in the future; perhaps your expertise is a bit limited.

Comment: At any rate, the basics of differentiable manifolds is not really differential geometry. Yes, differential forms and Stokes's Theorem certainly appear in complex analysis. The OP might be interested in looking at Steve Krantz's *Complex Analysis: The Geometric Viewpoint*, where hyperbolic metrics actually are the theme.

Comment: @Masacroso Funny, I was going to use the same word for you. I did research for 40 years in complex differential geometry.

Comment: @Masacroso To call complex analysis a subset of differential geometry is a gross oversimplification. There is definitely nontrivial intersections in the fields, but they are not remotely the same thing...

Comment: On a different note, I would also mention that the study of Riemann Surfaces and general complex manifolds can involve a fair amount of both complex analysis and manifold theory (the OP seems to define differential geometry as the study of manifolds, which while I would argue isn't quite specific enough, makes complex manifolds sound like exactly what the OP is looking for)

Comment: @Brevan I know. I dont wanted to say that complex analysis is a small piece of differential geometry. What I wanted to say is that many things of complex analysis are part of differential geometry (and, of course, algebraic topology, but algebraic topology is in many aspects fundamental to differential geometry), of course many others are not or at least cannot be seen as part of differential geometry

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry, I dont wanted to be rude before, my apologies. But sometimes you are a bit annoying. I take your point of view, can you see mine? Maybe my first comment was not about what had originally in mind. I wanted to say that many of complex analysis is part of differential geometry.

Comment: @Righter have you heard of Chern-Simons theories? Those might be up your alley (although one could argue that they are only loosely related to complex analysis, via contour integrals.)

Comment: @Righter you might also ask if there exists a correspondence between theorems concerning hol’c functions and closed differential forms in differential geometry (and if not, where the ‘obstacle’ appears.)